# MagicalRecord map String array to object

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

I'm using MagicalRecord to import json object to Core Data. I have a list of persons with `firstName` and `lastName` attributes. This works fine. each person has a list of `degrees` that is a simple array of strings. I would like to map this list of string to my `Degree` core data entity and map the string to the e.g. `Degree.name` attribute

```
[
  {
    "firstName": "ba",
    "lastName": "bar",
    "degrees": [
      "MSc",
      "BSc"
    ]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Fo",
    "lastName": "foo",
    "degrees": [
      "MSc"
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried using a empty `mappedKeyName` on the `name` attribute as described [here](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/wiki/Importing-Data) but it does not work.